# Pass arguments to parent class constructor in PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance, constructor

**I have 2 classes where parent is inherited by child.**

```
class parentClass
{
    private $table_name='';

    public function __construct($argument)
    {
        $this->table_name=$argument;
        echo $this->table_name;
    }
}

class child extends parentClass
{
    private $table="student";

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct($this->table);
    }
}
```

There is some thing like this below that has to be used but I am unable to understand how and why.

```
$args = func_get_args();
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::__construct'), $args);
```

**Help me as**

> What should be the correct code to achieve the correct logic
>   and please support it with a reference to gain a better understanding.

Comment: Actually, the concept of inheritance is a bit different, you can't call the constructor directly, it is called automatically. 

To pass along the $argument in the parent class, you need to provide it in the child class.

Comment: @Merv I some how need the value of **$table** to move to  **$table_name** i.e. child to parent.

Comment: @Merv the constructor of the parent class could be invoked automatically only if it doesn't have argument. But even in this case, this is not how PHP works. The programmer has to explicitly call the constructor of the parent class in the constructor of the derived class.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought you wanted to dynamically call the constructor to reflect the $arguments list in your example. Your problem is probably the fact you're using: `__constructor()` instead of the right `__construct()`

Comment: There no flaws in your logic, but two small flaws in your code. You can't use `parent` as a class name. You need to pick another name, and change `child extends parent` to the same name. But don't change `parent::__construct...`, here you use the reserved keyword. The second @Merv just mentioned, It's `__construct` not `constuctor`.

Comment: I actually missed the reserved keyword parent, nice catch.

Comment: @Merv Thanks, for pointing that out. So, by no means, a variable of the child could be passed over to parent using the constructor?

Comment: Yes, you can. Your code looks fine, if you change the class name of the `parent` to `ParentClass` or some other name, and change `__constructor()` to `__construct()` you should be fine.

Comment: The code in the question has been edited (to be valid, and working), which defeats the point of this question (which had invalid, non-working code, whose problems the OP wanted identified and described with improvements).  :(

Comment: The code in the question looks ok now. Of course you need to call `new child;`to see any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but if I read the code correctly, you don't really want to pass a variable / value to the constructor. Instead you want to pass a fixed class property like a table name.

In that case you could use a constant in the child class and set that in the parent's constructor. The child class would not need a separate constructor if that is all you want to do.

So [something like](https://eval.in/855202):

```
class parentClass
{
   private $table_name;

   function __construct() {
       $this->table_name = static::TABLE;
       echo $this->table_name;
   }
}

class childClass extends parentClass
{
    const TABLE = "student";
}

$obj = new childClass();
```

Comment: Thanks, man you actually got my question,

In case of an array I need to do this (I guess)?

define ("FRUITS", serialize (array ("apple", "cherry", "banana")));
$my_fruits = unserialize (FRUITS);

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava No, a constant can be an array, there is no need to serialize and unserialize.

Comment: There is no need for this to be a class constant. A plain old property will do just fine.

Comment: @salathe True, but for a table name of a class I would probably use a constant.